# Why does numpy.ndarray.resize() return None

Tags: python, numpy

I ran the following code in order to obtain a 2-by-3 array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(6).resize(2,3)
print(a)
```

However, the output is

```
None
```

Why is this? Many thanks

Comment: All operations in Python that operate in-place return None.

Comment: Many thanks! This makes it clear.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(6).reshape((2,3))
print(a)
```

to use resize :

```
a = np.arange(6)
a = np.resize(a, (2,3))
```

Comment: `reshape` doesn't change the base content. But `resize` should return a new array which is with the requested dimension. Is this right? I just wondered why my code doesn't return a new array.

Comment: I just checked the reference. What `ndarray.resize()` returns is exactly `None`. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: `reshape` need that the array have the same number of element. With `resize`, if  the new array is larger than the original array, then the new array is filled with repeated copies of a.